# Travel Greece with Italy Schengen issued visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I just learned that the roundtrip tickets to Greece is so cheap and I want to visit Greece for 2 days. My Schengen visa is 9 days long. I told the officer that I would stay in Italy the whole time as I was planning to and plus my hotel is non refundable. But now I wanna make small adjustments on my itinerary and fly to Greece for couple days and back during my stay. Do I get in trouble for that?